# How to extract only name initials from a complex string in Excel using formula?

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula

My Excel spreadsheet has strings with this structure, contained within single cells along column A:

```
[CELL A1]    
DOE_JOHN (123456) Series/Acq=5/1 (2017.01.01 01:01) SOL_TE30  TR/TE/NS=3000/30/64,  1.728E+00mL (M 044Y, 222kg)
```

From this string I'd like to only extract the subject's initials to place them in a new cell, as such:

`JD`

*So as you can see the order should be the character after the first underscore followed by the first character of the string.*

I've tried using LEFT and FIND, however have been unsuccessful.

Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this using a formula (not VBA)?

Comment: Are you always looking for the character after the first underscore and the first character of the string or are there other scenarios you can anticipate?

Comment: I'm looking for exactly what you mentioned: "the character after the first underscore and the first character of the string" in that order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-function-BE3191EA-D332-43E4-BAC3-810C97773A22) and [FIND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) with [CHAR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHAR-function-BBD249C8-B36E-4A91-8017-1C133F9B837A) like this.

```
=MID(A1, FIND(CHAR(95), A1)+1, 1)&LEFT(A1)
```

[image: Initials from Text]

Comment: this seems to capture only the first initial

Comment: @Dave - Thanks for catching that! Wasn't paying attention.

Comment: to the left of the formula bar, my Excel shows "table_3" instead of "A1" -- this may be because of the string structure or format?

Comment: You are using a structured table with its own unique references. Are there header labels? Is this in the second row of the table?

Comment: it may have references, data begins at 3rd row

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("_",A1)+1,1)&LEFT(A1)
```

Comment: Works for me but perhaps the underscore is non-standard if neither `"_"` or `CHAR(95)` picks it up.